# python empty list trick

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

I've got one little question about Python lists:

Why does this happen?

```
x = [[]] * 4
x[0].append('x') -> [['x'], ['x'], ['x'], ['x']]
```

Comment: Because you are copying the same list four times. And since in your list you have 4 lists all that point to the same memory space, if you modify one of them, the change will affect all.

Comment: Also, see [this entry in the Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the same instance of `[]` is being duplicated, so when you append to the first one `'x'`, you actually append it to all - because they are all the same object!

The right way to do it is to explicitly create a new list instance each time:

```
x = [[] for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: I added a possible solution to this answer. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: To be clear: The instance [] is not being *duplicated*. The expression `[[]] * 4` creates a list with four references to the same instance of [].

Comment: `[[]] * 4` looked like a nice trick to save some typing, but it bites people in the back afterwards by creating only two real lists and 3 references, which isn't so obvious. I used to do that too, but from now on I'll only use the list comprehension suggested here. Well, for such a small list `[[],[],[],[]]` is also fine. No need to show off using `[[]] * 4`. :)