# Python, appending a list to another list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I need to append a list to a 2D list so that I can edit the added list. I have something like this:

```
n = 3
a = [
    ['a', 2, 3],
    ['b', 5, 6],
    ['c', 8, 9]
]
b = [None for _ in range(n)]    # [None] * n
print b
a.append(b)
a[3][0] = 'e'
print a
a.append(b)
a[4][0] = 'f'
print a
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[None, None, None]
[['a', 2, 3], ['b', 5, 6], ['c', 8, 9], ['e', None, None]]
[['a', 2, 3], ['b', 5, 6], ['c', 8, 9], ['f', None, None], ['f', None, None]]
```

The `e` in 4th row changes to `f`, which I don't want. With `[None] * 3` I get same result. How do I prevent this from happening? I checked [how to create a fix size list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617045/how-to-create-a-fix-size-list-in-python?lq=1) and [python empty list trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554572/python-empty-list-trick) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your formulation could be improved: `b` is not an empty list, since its length is 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`b` is "pointing" to the same python object

You should do this instead to create new copies of `b`:

```
a.append(list(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your shallow copying the list instead of deep copying it (see: [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper) ).
Instead, you can use inbuilt module `copy` do the following:

```
import copy
# replace a.append(b) with the following
a.append(copy.deepcopy(b))
```