# Understanding lists of lists

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected feature in a Python list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists)
>   [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

Consider the following code:

```
a = [[]] * 3
a[1].append("foo")
```

I would expect the value of `a` to become:

```
[[], ["foo"], []]
```

instead, every element of `a` is updated:

```
[["foo"], ["foo"], ["foo"]]
```

Can someone please explain why did each element of the list got updated instead of just the defined element (`a[1]`)? Is there something fundamentally wrong in my logic?

For what it's worth I'm running Python2.7

Comment: This has been asked thousands of times.. Lemme find a duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks. It's difficult to find a proper title to this question, so I couldn't find a duplicate easily. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @rahmu: Yep, I know, it's unfortunate, but it's sure not your fault :) Have fun.

Comment: Yeah, it was pointed out before that you can't search for this problem unless you know what it is.

Comment: @rahmu: Symbolhound is however quite good at finding small code snippets: [Search results for `[[]] * ` on Stackoverflow](http://symbolhound.com/?q=python&l=&e=%5B%5B%5D%5D+*&n=&u=stackoverflow.com) The third result is already a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are objects, this means when you assign a list to another variable, changing either will change the actual list, for example

```
a = []
b = a
b.append("hi")
print a
// a is now ["hi"]
```

When you do the assignment

```
a = [[]] * 3
```

It's the same as saying

```
inner_list = []
outer_list = [inner_list, inner_list, inner_list]
```

In other words, all the inner lists are the *same* object. Not different objects as you think.

To get the effect you want, you should do:

```
outer_list = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    outer_list.append([])
```

Which creates a 3 inner lists objects and puts the into the outer object.

Comment: The usual way to do this is using a list comprehension: `lst = [[] for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find what is happening is that what python is doing is creating:

```
outer_list = []
inner_list = []
outer_list = [inner_list,inner_list,inner_list]
```

or to explain it more clearly,
`outer_list` and inner list are created once, and then `inner_list` is copied `* 3` into `outer_list`, which means all 3 lists in the `outer_list` are actually a reference to the same `inner_list` copied 3 times.