# strange indexing behavior upon initializing a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I just spent an hour with the following frustration, and

a) wanted to post it in case someone else has the same problem, and
b) i am very curious what underlies this behavior.

```
$ e = [{}]*6
$ e
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
$ e[0]['green'] = 'blue'
$ e
[{'green': 'blue'}, {'green': 'blue'}, {'green': 'blue'}, {'green': 'blue'}, {'green': 'blue'}, {'green': 'blue'}]
$ e = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
$ e
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
$ e[0]['green'] = 'blue'
$ e
[{'green': 'blue'}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Basically, the problem is when a list of dictionaries is initialized with [{}]*int, attempts to modify a single dictionary by its index in the list modifies all dictionaries.  Whereas explicitly initializ

Thanks

Comment: This link may also be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/10259763/1209279

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are putting same `dict` 6 times. `[{}]*6` wouldn't copy/deepcopy the original dict but only the reference to it. If you want 6 separate dict use a loop/list comprehension e.g

```
e = [{} for i in range(6)]
```

See more explanation in [python doc](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list)

Comment: That's right! To elaborate, when you do `[X] * N` in Python, all you are saying is *give me N references to X in a list* (where X can be any mutable type). They all end up pointing to the same thing and changing any one of them ends up changing all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **mutability**. And it is not strange.

In first case:

```
>>> e = [{}]*6
```

you create a list from **one dictionary repeated 6 times**. If you change one of the elements, you change the other elements (at least it looks like, because in fact these "other" elements are the same element).

In the second case:

```
>>> e = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

you created a list from **6 different dictionaries**, so changing one does not influence the others.