# Python lists confusion

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

I am a bit puzzled with lists of lists in Python. I have these two snippets:

```
li1 = [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
print li1
for i in range(0, len(li1)):
    li1[i] += [i]
print li1

li2 = [['a']] * 3
print li2
for i in range(0, len(li2)):
    li2[i] += [i]
print li2
```

After creation li1 and li2 are the same, but when I add elements they behave differently:

```
[['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
[['a', 0], ['a', 1], ['a', 2]]
[['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
[['a', 0, 1, 2], ['a', 0, 1, 2], ['a', 0, 1, 2]]
```

Could some one please explain where the trick is?

Comment: I tried to look for similar questions but could actually formulate the problem, so asked.

Comment: And you didn't see the question that had practically the *exact same title* as the one you're asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `li2 = [['a']] * 3` you create one list with three list elements but these lists are actually the same object. That means: when you modify `li2[0]`, you also modify `li2[1]` and `li2[2]`.

The following line actually creates a list with three different list objects inside it:

```
li1 = [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

In this case, when you modify `li1[0]` you only modify that list. The other lists are unaffected. This explains why you are getting different lists in `li1` and `li2`.

Answer (score 1):

check the value of `id()` for each element,which clearly suggest the reason of their behavior.

```
>>> li1 = [['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
>>> for x in li1:                  #different id()
    id(x)


145497484
145514156
145511500
```

Same values of `id()`:

```
>>> li1=['a']*3
>>> for x in li1:
    print id(x)


3078093024
3078093024
3078093024
```