# python a=[[],]*10

Tags: python, list, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

When I write a simple python script, I define a new list as follows:

```
A=[[],]*10
```

What I wanna do is just initialize a list whose length is 10 and each element is a empty list.

And when I do something like:

```
A[0].append(["abc",])
```

I just wanna append this `["abc",]` to `A[0]`, and it turn out to be that every elements in A is appended with `["abc",]`

I know this probably due to my initialization (`A=[[],]*10`) . I just want to know why this happened.

Comment: `[x,]` likely is better written as `[x]`. In any case, note that `list*int` does *not* clone objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a list with 10 references to the same empty list.

You should use a list comprehension instead:

```
A = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

In a list comprehension, you create a new list for every iteration through the loop. If you are using python 2, you should use `xrange` instead of `range` (although with only 10 elements that won't make much difference).

Answer (score 3):

Your expression `A=[[]]*10` is equivalent to:

```
a = []
A = [a]*10
```

This means that A consists of 10 references to one and the same list.

Answer (score 1):

All the empty lists are references to the same object.