# Appending a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of lists. I want to add the elements of an array to one of the sublists, but the one I add it to depends on the length of the array.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg
from numpy import matrix
from scipy.linalg import inv,det,eig
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from numpy import vstack
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from array import array
import copy

def getstabmat(orign, small, specsize, alln):
    #FIRST MAKE THE MATRIX
    matfound=0
    while (matfound==0):
        n=orign
        A=np.empty((n,n))
        I=np.ones((n))
        for i in range(0,n):
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                A[j,i]=random.random()
        for i in range(0,n):
            for j in range(i+1,n):
                    A[i,j] = A[j,i]
        for i in range(n):
            A[i,i]=1
        #NOW REMOVE NEGATIVE ELEMENTS AND KEEP SOLVING
        allpos=0
        while (allpos !=1): #loop for dealing just with getting it positive
            x = numpy.linalg.solve(A,I)
            if any(tl<small for tl in x): #if any of the solutions in x are negative or small
                p=np.where(x==min(x)) # find the most negative solution, p is the position
                x=np.delete(x, p, 0)
                A=np.delete(A, p, 0)
                A=np.delete(A, p, 1)
                I=np.delete(I, p, 0)
                n=n-1
            else:
                allpos=1
        #now test for stability, only do it once and remove one element before returning to check positiveness.
        J=np.empty((n,n)) # make empty jacobian
        for i in range (0,n):
            for j in range (0,n):
                if (i==j): # if we are looking at the diagonal of the matrix, there is a special formula for species dealing with itself
                    tsum = 0
                    for k in range (0,n): #for the summation part
                        tsum = tsum + A[i][k]*x[k] # x is vector of fixed points obtained before
                    J[i][j] = 1 - A[i][j]*x[i] - tsum
                else:
                    J[i][j] = -A[i][j]*x[i]
                    #now jacobian at fixed point has been constructed
        Jeig, Jvec =  eig(J) # get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
        #run through eigenvalues and find out if any of them are positive
        if any(tl>0 for tl in Jeig.real): #if any eigenvalues are positive
            matfound=0
        else:
            if ((alln==0 and len(A)==specsize) or alln==1): # if the matrix found has five species
                matfound=1
            else:
                matfound=0
    return A, x

def main():

    mats=3 #number of matrices to find
    orign=15
    alln=1 #if alln=1, that means that all sizes of stable matrix should be returned
    n=5 # the number of different species wanted in each matrix
    small=0.0001 #the fractional size that a species is when it is considered to be extinct
    a=0
    sortedspec=[[]]*10
    specad=[]
    while (a<mats): #while all the mats have not been found
        print a
        A, specfp = getstabmat(orign, small, n, alln) #15 is the original size of matrix to pass to fnc.n is the size that will be returned
        a=a+1
        print specfp
        print len(specfp)
        for i in range (0,len(specfp)):
            (sortedspec[len(specfp)]).append(specfp[i])
    print sortedspec

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

So if:

```
specfp = [ 0.78076862  0.79608003  0.50719552]
```

Then I want each element to be added to the list sortedspec[3]. However, I end up with each element of my array being added to EVERY list element. Why is it doing this and can I fix it? Thankyou.

Comment: Maybe start by removing everything from your code that is not related to this problem.

Comment: Why not use defaultdict and append elements (or add lists)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python list confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sortedspec=[[]]*10
```

This will make your list contain 10 references to the same (single) sublist, so updating one of them will be reflected in the others as well:

```
>>> sortedspec[0].append(1)
>>> sortedspec
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

What you need to do instead is create 10 different lists, for example using a list comprehension:

```
sortedspec=[[] for i in range(10)]
```