# How to append an object to multi-dimension list

Tags: android, python, list, sl4a

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

This is a quiestion about list of python.
(My programming environment is SL4A with python)

I want a list below with inputted  number "n".

```
[ ['a'] , [] , [] , [] ] # (this example is the list when n =4)    <- the list I want
```

So, I wrote a source-code below.

```
n = input()
array = [[]]*n
array[0].append('a')
print array
```

However, I can' get an output above, but also get a list as like...

```
[ ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'] ] #  <- wrong list
```

So, I have two questions.

1. Please tell me a source-code which is give me a list what I want.
2. Why does the source-code give me the wrong list?

Comment: Thanks for editting my question and telling me  a past question I should comfirm before I post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
array = [[] for x in range(n)]
```

Otherwise you get 4 references to the *same* list

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
array = [[]]*n
```

you will get a list with n same links. That is why when you edit one of the element you edit every element.
To get rid of this just use something like this

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    array1.append([])
    array2+=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### python 3.2:

```
n = input()
array = [[] for i in range(n)]
array[0].append('a')
print array
```

Comment: In Python 3.2 `print` is a function, so I don't think this syntax works?

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.