# Initializing and updating a multidemensional array python3

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I need to initialize a multidimensional array from an integer `n`.

```py
n = 2

list_1 = [[] for _ in range(n)]
list_2 = [[]] * n
```

Then I append `2` to the first item in the nD-array as below.

```py
list_1[0].append(2)
list_2[0].append(2)
```

```py
print('After')
print(list_1) # [[2], []]
print(list_2) # [[2], [2]] Why this happen?
```

You could find the code [here](https://repl.it/@Nhat_AnhAnh/BuzzingStunningFirmware#main.py).

I'm new to python. Could anyone explain in-depth why when I use `[[]] *n`, it will update all child arrays in `list_2`?

Comment: From what I can tell this is because in `list_1` every item is uniquely created but in `list_2` all the items are duplicates of each other. So, whatever happens to one item in `list_2` will happen to the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive answer here: [Python list confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957341/python-list-confusion)

Basically when the array is initialized with *n, it will copy the address of the first element to all the rest.